# Ramanujan-Type Double Sum Infinite Series for $1/\pi$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request, elliptic-integrals

$$\sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{2m}{m}\binom{2n+2m}{n+m}^3\left(\frac{1+6n+6m}{2^{10n+10m}}\right)=\frac{4}{\pi}$$

These are Ramanujan-Type Series for $1/\pi$ but based on a Double Sum Infinite Series.

Basically it's based on the following expansion of Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind $K$ with parameter $k$.

$$K=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{2m}{m}\binom{2n+2m}{n+m}^2\frac{k^{2n+2m}}{2^{6n+6m}}$$

From here on we can follow the similar process as deriving the normal $1/\pi$ series.

I haven't particularly seen these double sum ones, so was wondering whether anyone has worked upon them and looking for some reference on these.

Comment: Ramanujan's technique requires a series for $(2K/\pi)^2$. Do you have the corresponding series for $K^2$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh We can just use this to arrive at series for $K^2$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}K(2kk'\sin t)dt=K^2$$

Comment: That's a nice result and its new for me. The traditional proof linking $K$ and $K^2$ is based on Clausen formula. Do you have any integral formula corresponding to Clausen formula?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh This is exactly Clausen's Formula in disguise. There is another result too (not sure if this one is related to Clausen or not)
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}K\left(\sqrt{1-(2kk'\sin t)^2}\right)dt=KK'$$

and
$\int_0^{\pi/2}K\left[\sqrt{(\alpha\sin t)^2+(\beta \cos t)^2}\right]dt$
is known too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite it by substituting $k=m+n$,
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\left ( 6n+1 \right ) \left ( \frac12 \right )_n^3 }{2^{4n}(1)_n^3} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n-2k}{n-k} 
=\frac{4}{\pi}.
$$
The inner binomial sum is elementary and equals $2^{2n}$, giving the common type of Ramanujan's $\pi$ formula.
Z.W. Sun once conjectured lots of series identities in the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5649v19). Some of them involve similar factors but seem much harder to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the Reference!